# How to provide a value to every component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm somewhat new to React Native.

I am trying to add a value to every component, essentially login information.

I am using this library:

https://github.com/mahomahoxd/react-native-login-keycloak

You get the login information this way:

```
import Login from 'react-native-login-keycloak';


const gatheredTokens = await Login.getTokens();
```

Now obviously, an await needs to be inside an async function, so I am trying it as follows:

```
async componentWillMount() {
    const gatheredTokens = await Login.getTokens();
    this.setState({ gatheredTokens: this.state.gatheredTokens });
}
```

However this seems messy - first off, componentWillMount is apparently being deprecated (I suppose I could switch it to componentDidMount instead) and also it requires me to essentially duplicate this process in each and every component. Messy code duplication!

What's a purer way to do this? I'm guessing something along the lines of a higher order component or some other structure?

Can someone give me an example of how I would provide this to all of my components (I am using Redux, so via Redux or another method is fine) - I'm just not sure how I can ensure that the data is processed and available everywhere it needs to be, and I want the most, "React" way of doing it.

Comment: You could fetch this data from a parent component and pass it to each of the child components as a prop.

Comment: If you're using redux then just set in your central state and map it to any components that would need access to the data. There are plenty of examples in the redux docs: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: Use redux selectors? `mapStateToProps` or pass them down as a prop from a parent component.

Comment: @MattAft - would I just do that in my store.js or in a separate action/reducer? Can you write up a quick example? I more or less understand Redux, but I've only been using it for a few months

Comment: You would need an action/reducer set up if you want to be able to modify the state values. The link i provided gives you an example for a simple todo app. The question is also do you want this to be saved if the app closes to automatically log them in? because then you can use RN's async storage instead: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Comment: I want them to be automatically logged in, yes

Comment: This might be your business call but this isn't correct to automatically logged in user if the App is closed. It is fine to do so if it's in background but not when the whole app is closed.

Comment: @MilindAgrawal Unfortunately, the stakeholders disagree

Comment: In that case you can use the asyncstorage from RN as suggested above or a third party library `react-native-simple-store`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that, render Props, Higher order component, and even hooks - not sure whether at the time i write this hooks are supported for React Native.

Anyway since you suggested a Higher Order Component, then my solution will use a one

```
export const withGatheredTokens = Component => {
  class WithGatheredTokens extends React.Component {
    state = { gatheredTokens: null };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const gatheredTokens = await Login.getTokens();
        this.setState({ gatheredTokens });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component gatheredTokens={this.state.gatheredTokens} {...props} />
      );
    }
  }

  return WithGatheredTokens;
};

// And this is how you use with with a Another Component
export AnotherComponent =  withGatheredTokens(AnotherComponentBase)
```

And anyway network requests should always be done in ComponendDidUpdate and not a componentWillMount method.

Comment: I believe you mean for this line to be this.setState({ gatheredTokens:gatheredTokens });

Comment: @CecilRodriguez yea thats true, i edited my answer. also you can use the es6 shorthand property here to make code smaller (i did that in my edit)

Comment: @ehab Nice one. I think this will work in a way that for every screen I go that has my imported component, if `Login.getToken` is not completed, it will keep calling the componentDidMount function over and over again

Comment: @OluwasayoBabalola no, componentDidMount gets called only once when the component is mounted (unless the component gets unmounted and remounted again). However before the data is fetched the Wrapped Component will receive the gathered tokens as null (The initial state for them as we specified ), and once the data is fetched, the HigherOrderComponent will re-render giving its Child the new value of gatheredTokens

Comment: @ehab right, understood. componentDidMount gets called only once. Interesting! Will read further on this +1

Answer (score 1):

Using Redux

create your `actions` and `reducers`

//you may name your action file as loginAction.js with

```
export const setLoginData = data => {
  return {
    type: SET_LOGIN_TOKEN,
    payload: data
  }
};
```

//and your reducer as

```
export default (state = {}, action = {}) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case SET_LOGIN_DATA:
         return {...state, loginData: action.payload};

      default:
        return state;
   }
}
```

//don't forget to apply your store to `App.js` wrapping `View` with //

**Use**
At login when you get token

```
async componentDidMount() {
   const gatheredTokens = await Login.getTokens();
   this.setState({ gatheredTokens: gatheredTokens });
   //this.setLoginData(gatheredTokens); 
   //having imported `setLoginData` from your login action, and also used `mapDispatchToProps`
}
```

then your loginData should be available everywhere you need it when you do

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   loginData: state.loginData,
});
```

then you can access token in loginData as

```
const loginToken = this.props.loginData;
```

Comment: Is this approach or the HOC approach "better" would you say?

Comment: I believe either is fine. It depends on which best works for your use case. @CecilRodriguez